# Cannot enter password from second keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, thinkpad, docking-station

I have an IBM ThinkPad x220 with docking station.

My system is Windows 7 x64.

When I unlock the computer, I cannot do it from keyboard attached through docking station. It does not recognize the password. I have to put the password from my laptop keyboard and then it works. Is this some issue related to language/keyboard layout assigned to each keyboard?

Or is there any other cause? What can I do to fix it?

Yes, the symbols **** are showing on the screen wen I'm typing on external keyboard.

Comment: Do the ••••• symbols appear when you enter the password from the external keyboard?

Comment: Try toggling the Shift lock and/or the Num lock keys.